# Error in SMS sending to multiple contacts

Tags: android, bluetooth, sms

I am developing an app which is integrated with a wrist band which monitors heart rate & temperature of human body. If there is any certain issues in health,from the mobile which is connected with wrist band via bluetooth is sent SMS to all saved contact group.

Everything  is working good.**But instead of sending only one message, it sends more than one messages to an individual.**

Contact numbers & contact names are stored in local DB.And by collecting the number from DB,it sends SMS.

```
String mobile = ed2.getText().toString();

if (p1 == 1) {
Log.e("SMS HERE", "Heart Beat is LOW");
for (int i = 0; i < curContact.getCount(); i++) {

    //sms.sendTextMessage(contactNo.get(i), null, " My Heart Beat is LOW." + "\n" + "Now I am in this location" + " " + Splash.strAddress, null, null);
                            sms.sendTextMessage(curContact.getString(curContact.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.CONTACT_PHONE)), null, " My Heart Beat is LOW." + "\n" + "Now I am in this location" + " " + Splash.strAddress, null, null);
                        }
                    } else if (p1 == 3) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < curContact.getCount(); i++) {

                            sms.sendTextMessage(curContact.getString(curContact.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.CONTACT_PHONE)), null, "My Heart Beat is HIGH." + "\n" + "Now I am in this location" + " " + Splash.strAddress, null, null);

                        }
                    } else if (p2 == 4) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < curContact.getCount(); i++) {
sms.sendTextMessage(curContact.getString(curContact.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.CONTACT_PHONE)), null, "My Temperature is LOW." + "\n" + "Now I am in this location" + " " + Splash.strAddress, null, null);
                        }
                    } else if (p2 == 5) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < curContact.getCount(); i++) {
                            sms.sendTextMessage(curContact.getString(curContact.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.CONTACT_PHONE)), null, "My Temperature is LOW." + "\n" + "Now I am in this location" + " " + Splash.strAddress, null, null);
                        }
```

Comment: It's going to send as many emails to each subject as you have in your contact list the way your code is written.

Comment: Where I need to change.?

Comment: You're not advancing the `Cursor` in your loops, so your code is just sending the selected message to the first phone number `curContact.getCount()` number of times.